# Complex transaction pairing in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a dataset of transactions. In it, I can identify what group of transactions a line belongs to by its ID. The remove column is highly compressed- it flags if a line needs to be removed or stays. However, in order to make the removed column works, everything needs to be sorted a particular way - ID first, Date second(Oldest to newest), Amount 3rd (Largest to smallest).

Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhr6k.jpg

So here are the rules that I'm trying to follow:

1) If a negative transaction occurs before any positive transactions, we're throwing it out - this is the general gist of what's going on with the remove column.

2) We need to pair the negative transactions with their corresponding offset positive transaction - however, the positive transaction needs to come first (or at the same time).

I've figure out how to do 1 and 2 - that's the current set of formulas given. However, where I'm struggling is:

3) Pair negative transactions with their most recent debit, instead of the first debit that'll offset it. The example of where this would change is highlighted in yellow.

This is already fairly calculation-intensive, and ideally I'd like it to scale over 600,000 transactions (It's already messy with the countifs - generally I'll find the largest count of the same ID, then slide the countifs to only cover the largest range). How can I, preferably with pure formulas, get rule 3 implemented? I'll accept VBA if that's the only way to do it in a timely fashion.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but wouldn't sorting by column D solve for your pairing? In theory, if you're assigning item specific IDs based on the amount and the count of the amount, they would be in chronological order. I'm having a hard time picturing what you want though, so I'm probably way off. In your image, is the goal state the "B" Id lines?

Comment: The goal state is the new date column - I'd like to assign the date of the debit that the credit offsets so that they appear on the same day. (My actual challenge is to get it into the same month, but I'm having a hard time imagining a situation where you can get the month but not the day)

Comment: Sorry I'm still not sure what you're really trying to accomplish, but I'll leave some info for getting just the month from a date. The formula =TEXT([date],"MMM") will produce a 3-character Month for a date. So, =TEXT(E2,"MMM") will produce "Jan". Make it =TEXT(E2,"MMMM") for "January" or "MMM-YY" for "Jan-18"

Comment: I mean, sorting by column D would work - the trick is generating column D, which is what I'm currently doing. Will probably end up putting a bounty on the question